# Use Xpath with pandas read_xml python

Tags: python, pandas, xml, xpath

I want to import all information about the supported Xep's from the .doap files and return them as dataframe. Therefore I tried to use pandas.read_xml().

```
#python
import pandas as pd


Clients={"Monal":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monal-im/Monal/develop/monal.doap", # works as espected
        "Profanity":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/profanity-im/profanity/master/profanity.doap", #error
       "Dino":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dino/dino/master/dino.doap"  #handle multiple languages
        #... more listed Clients
        }

namespaces={"default":"http://usefulinc.com/ns/doap#",
    "rdf":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "xmpp":"https://linkmauve.fr/ns/xmpp-doap#",
    "schema":"https://schema.org",
    "xml":"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace",
    "foaf":"http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"}

for i in Clients.keys():
    liste = pd.read_xml(Clients[i]).transpose() # works without problem
    xep = pd.read_xml(Clients[i], xpath=".//xmpp:xep",namespaces=namespaces)
    Features = pd.read_xml(Clients[i], xpath=".//xmpp:SupportedXep",namespaces=namespaces)
    Features['xep_URL']=xep['resource']
```

Is it possible to get only one language (when I import Dino, the last language remains)?

```
...
            output:          needed output (xml:lang='en'):
...
name        Dino             Dino
shortdesc   تطبيق حديث للدرد Modern XMPP Chat Client...
description إنّ Dino برنامج   Dino is a modern open-...
```

And how do I fix the error which occurs when the Profanity .doap file is imported and make it reliable for new unexpected Namespaceprefixes?

```
Namespace prefix foaf on Person is not defined
```

Comment: `//rdf:implements` xpath must include namespace prefixes in this case

Comment: Nope (Xpath="//rdf:implements"):
SyntaxError: You have used an incorrect or unsupported XPath expression for etree library or you used an undeclared namespace prefix.
With xpath=Xpath=".//rdf:implements": Old error

Comment: Error has nothing to do with `pandas` or `lxml`. The profanity document is not-well formed XML due to the error raised. Use any online validator and see. The other two are well-formed and has no issues. Reach out to authors/maintaners of that GitHub repo to update that markup document (which does not pass as XML).

Comment: *Is it possible to get only one language (when I import Dino, the last language remains)?* Are you asking two questions here. Please keep one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your expected output is, but if you use local-name() instead of namespaces, you could do something like this (using your 2nd url and element as an example):

```
url = 'https://dev.gajim.org/gajim/gajim/-/raw/master/data/gajim.doap'
req = requests.get(url)
df = pd.read_xml(req.text, xpath=".//*[local-name()='SupportedXep']")
df
```

Output is:

```
0   NaN     complete    2.9     None    None
1   NaN     complete    1.3     PGP Plugin  None
2   NaN     complete    2.4     None    None
3   NaN     partial     1.1     Used to send one message to several JIDs at th...   None
4   NaN     complete    1.31.2  None    None
```

etc.

EDIT:

What you're asking for probably can't be done with `read_xml()`. Try this, though it can probably be simplified:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = 'https://dev.gajim.org/gajim/gajim/-/raw/master/data/gajim.doap'
req = requests.get(url)

targets = doc.xpath('//xmpp:SupportedXep',namespaces=ns)
columns = ['xep','status','since','version','note']
rows = []
for target in targets:
    row = []
    resource = target.xpath('.//@rdf:resource',namespaces=ns)[0].split('xep-')[1].split('.')[0]
    status=target.xpath('.//xmpp:status/text()',namespaces=ns)[0]
    version=target.xpath('.//xmpp:version/text()',namespaces=ns)[0]
    since = target.xpath('.//xmpp:since/text()',namespaces=ns)
    f_since = since[0] if len(since)>0 else ""
    note=target.xpath('.//xmpp:note/text()',namespaces=ns)
    f_note = note[0] if len(note)>0 else ""
    row.extend([resource,status,f_since,version,f_note])
    rows.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
df.transpose()
```

Comment: The first column should be the XEP URL or the XEP number and not NaN. And it would be good to know where the error for the client profanity comes from. The link is in rdf:resource (see also edited question above).

Comment: I tried to run your program, but it does not work for me. First I replaced doc.xpath by etree.XPath to fix the first error, then I got the error targets is not iterable. I'm not sure if this was caused by my first error correction, but at the moment this does not work.
@JackFleeting

Comment: I think I fixed the issue which I described before, but I'm still not at the point where I want to be. Profanity throws an error and I have to select a default language for my import.